# Could batch file recognize the fields in the cfg file?

Tags: batch-file, configuration, config

I have cfg file which has two fields : test.cfg

```
[Test_1] = 12345
TC_1=testCase/String_print.tc -arg "Indonesia" -logToConsole
TC_2=testCase/test2.tc -c "ramen" -logToConsole

[Test_2] = 12346
TC_1= testCase/test.tc -c "olleH" -logToConsole
```

And bat file test.bat

```
@ECHO off

set var=C:\Users\syuniyar\.EasyTest\4\ccl\config\test2.cfg
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (%var%) DO (
    SET line=%%a
    IF "!line:~0,7!"=="Test_1=" SET Test_1=!line:~7! (
            FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (%var%) DO (
                IF "!line:~0,5!"=="TC_1=" SET TC_1=!line:~5!
                IF "!line:~0,5!"=="TC_2=" SET TC_2=!line:~5!
)
)
)
SET TC_1=%TC_1:;=%
SET TC_2=%TC_2:;=%

ECHO %TC_1%
ECHO %TC_2%
```

I want to retrieve the TC_1 in Test_1 = 12345 which has the value 'testCase/String_print.tc -arg "Indonesia" -logToConsole'. But from the current code what I got is 'testCase/test.tc -c "olleH" -logToConsole' which is from 12346. It returns the last item matched. My questions are : Is it possible that batch file recognizes something like Test_1\TC_1? Before I tried using array but it stored all the element from cfg file into one single array.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Your description is not clear. Given the test.cfg file above and _which input_ what is the _output_ you want? Please, add this info editing the question and just leave me a comment here as an advice of that.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I changed it a bit. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

This Batch file do what you requested:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get the line number of "[Test_1]"
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /L /B "[Test_1]" test2.cfg') do set lines=%%a

rem Get the TC_1 line after previous one
for /F "skip=%lines% tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (test2.cfg) do (
   if "%%a" equ "TC_1" set "%%a=%%b" & goto continue
)
:continue

echo TC_1=%TC_1%
```